# JavaScript line and area chart with similar interface as shown

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is there any chart API which can provide a similar interface as shown in the image?

I have worked on amcharts and highcharts before but after endless tweakings I could'nt get them to look similar to the one shown in the image. Especially:

- Ability to use gradients
- Bullets in the line chart

So far I have explored (not worked on them) these other APIs: d3, fusion charts, rickshaw, protoshart, flotr but none the examples shown on their look similar to the one as shown.

There are a large number of charts API and cannot explore each and every one.

[image: Area chart][image]

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts can give you a gradient, e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/afgdwukw/

```
 series: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 300, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }
```

You can specifiy multiple stops to transition between different colours.

I can't see anything in your images which can't be done in highcharts. If you have a specific issue you are struggling with, post a question for the specific issue, preferably with a jsfiddle showing what you have tried so far.

I don't seen anything in your images which can't be done with highcharts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir....I'll create the fiddle for the specific issues I am facing and post my question again....but for the time sake....can we combine stacked area chart with line chart....and can we have spacing in the data points(for line chart) as shown in the figure....

Comment: You can combine charts, you can space data points how you like, you can even do the little circle charts with the percentages in the middle.